# Placement of delete filters button - inside or next to dropdown?

Tags: buttons, filter, dropdown, placement

So I have a pretty simple "problem": I have a filter option, which is this dropdown as you can see in the pictures.

The question is: what do you think is the better placement for the delete button, which deletes the selected filters?

The 2 options are: outside the dropdown, sticking right next to the dropdown toggler on the right side.

[image: Outside]

Or inside the dropdown, together with the other 2 buttons.

[image: Inside]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only options are inside or outside, I'd definitely go with outside.

You'd want the user to be able to know there are filters applied without having to open the dropdown to check.

I'd also recommend changing "Delete" to "Clear" or "Reset".